# Text box translation into address

Tags: c#, winforms

I work in an environment where we do a lot of remote troubleshooting.  I am developing a C# <strike>Console</strike> Windows Application that speeds the process of logging into different programs.

It is a multi-tabbed application where on the first Window, there is a text box where the user enters a site number.

What I would like help with is how can I write a code that will read that 3 or 4-digit site number and translate it into an IP address?

In one part of the application, I need it to translate it into an IP address inside a URL.  For example, say the user wants to connect to a server at site 1234. They enter 1234 in the text box on the main page and then click connect on the Server tab. I need the site number to implant itself inside a URL looking something like //10.12.34.1:80/.

Comment: What did you try so far and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: I'm not sure where to begin with it.  I'm still new with C# and I have been feeling my way around it.  Even if there was a way where I could simply take the ID in the text box and use Sendkeys to send it as a divided number, that would be perfect.  So if they entered a 3-digit site ID (123), it would send "1.23" and if they entered a 4-digit site ID, it would separate it like "12.34". I could always hard code the first and fourth octets in there.

Comment: okay... so what is it you are having problems with? This is not a site to "want" something. Describe your problem getting there and you will get help.

Comment: @user3459000 I think you are aware of the problem how to reliably decide how to split your user input - i.e. how would you want to decide if "1234" means `.1.234.` or `.12.34.` or `.123.4.`? How dynamic are those IP addresses? Could you put them in a DropDown instead (maybe backed by a database)?

Comment: My problem is that I do not know how to translate a 3-digit or 4-digit number in a text box into the second and third octets of an IP address.  I just want assistance with coding that or pointed in the right direction in how that can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this only for the sake of showing you that your simplified requirements can be easily achieved.

If you only need to decide between 3 and 4 char input values and hardcode the start and end of the target IP address this should do the trick:

```
string userinput; // 3 or 4 char user input from TextBox
string secondoctet = string.Empty;
string thirdoctet = string.Empty;

if (userinput.Length == 3)
{
    secondoctet = userinput.Substring(0, 1);
    thirdoctet = userinput.Substring(1, 2);
}

if (userinput.Length == 4)
{
    secondoctet = userinput.Substring(0, 2);
    thirdoctet = userinput.Substring(2, 2);
}

// using hardcoded IP format template inserting 2nd and 3rd octet into placeholders
string targetip = string.Format("10.{0}.{1}.1", secondoctet, thirdoctet);
```

Please keep in mind that this solution is restricted to the simple rule that 3-char input will always be split in 1-2 and 4-char input will always be split in 2-2.

As already mentioned in my comment without doubt you will soon face requirements for splitting according to different rules.